# Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is my query everything is working fine in development mode but in production it give error.

```
<?php

$sql = "INSERT INTO `order_utm` VALUES('',:order_id,:utm_source,:utm_campaign,:utm_medium,:tim)";
$result = $this->query($sql, 'insert', array(
    'order_id' => $trans_id,
    'utm_source' => $utm_source,
    'utm_campaign' => $utm_campaign,
    'utm_medium' => $utm_medium,
    'tim' => time()
));
```

Comment: Please check into `VALUES(''`, -> This looks the reason for defect.

Comment: check the dev and prod DB's, maybe you have different settings on them and activate errors on the page like this:
`error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);`

Comment: Checked both have same setting data is inserted both server after insert live server give error

Comment: will you post the table scheme?